# How to set Callbacks on PhoneAuthOptions in Firebase PhoneAuth?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

"I just started learning Firebase"

I did set callbacks in PhoneAuthOptions yet I keep getting the error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: You must specify callbacks on your PhoneAuthOptions. Please call #setCallbacks().

**This is my first activity**, from which I am getting user's phone number and passing it to second activity:

```
public class SendOTPActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mPhoneNumber;
private Button mBtnSendOtp;
String phoneNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_o_t_p);

    mPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
    mBtnSendOtp = findViewById(R.id.btn_send_otp);

    phoneNumber = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

    mBtnSendOtp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),VerifyOTPActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("PHONE_NUMBER",phoneNumber);
            startActivity(intent);

            mBtnSendOtp.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**This is second activity (Verification Activity):**

```
public class VerifyOTPActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mOtpCode;
private Button mBtnVerifyOtp;
private TextView textView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

private String phoneNumber;
private String code;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;

private  String mVerificationId;

private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_o_t_p);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mOtpCode = findViewById(R.id.otp_code);
    mBtnVerifyOtp = findViewById(R.id.btn_verify_otp);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("PHONE_NUMBER");
    code = mOtpCode.getText().toString();

    textView.setText("An OTP has been sent to +91 "+phoneNumber);

    startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber);

    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if (code!=null){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                Toast.makeText(VerifyOTPActivity.this, "Provided phone number might not be correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                Toast.makeText(VerifyOTPActivity.this, "Some error has occurred please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            mVerificationId = s;
            mResendToken = token;
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        // Update UI
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            Toast.makeText(VerifyOTPActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber){
    PhoneAuthOptions options =
            PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                    .setPhoneNumber("+91"+phoneNumber)
                    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .setActivity(this)
                    .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)
                    .build();
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCreate` you call `startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber);` before you create your `OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks`. Try to move `startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber);` below the block where you create your callback. That should get rid of the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks for your time @FelixNovovic, that did the trick. One more error just occurred, FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException, that's error for invalid phone number format. I did add the country code, so why did this error occur?

Comment: If the answer resolved your question please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Fur further inquiries create a new question. I do not know what you are actually sending to Firebase, so I can only refer you to the relevant [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException).